# Breaking a range of values into buckets for a gradient

Tags: web-mapping, cartography, algorithm, choropleth

If I have a range of values and want to make a choropleth map with a gradient, what algorithms are out there to determine the value ranges for the different colors in the gradient?

For example, if I have a dataset with the values 1,10,40,50,2000,123,23,68,39,21,10,800,600,200 and want to color 14 states based on those values, what is the best way to determine the ranges?

Something like [1-50]= light red, [51-100] red, [101-2000] dark red

Comment: You might want to add (hypothetical) information about the areas of the states, the areas of the polygons used to represent them on the map, the nature of the data (counts? densities?) and the *purpose* of the map: all these (and more) have entered into various solutions to your problem in important ways.

Answer (score 2):

[Chroma.js](https://github.com/gka/chroma.js) library gives some methods to create color-ramps : https://github.com/gka/chroma.js/wiki/Color-Scales#auto-generated-limits. They are based on standard classification algorithms but may be extended if you need a more complex approach.

Example (from [wiki page](https://github.com/gka/chroma.js/wiki/Color-Scales)) :

```
scale = new chroma.ColorScale({
colors: ['#F7E1C5', '#6A000B'],
limits: chroma.limits(data, 'k-means', 5)
})
```

And implemented methods :

> The descriptions are written by Gabriel Florit:
>
> *equal*: In the equal intervals classification system, the entire range of values is divided equally into the desired number of intervals.
>
> *quantiles*: In the quantiles system, each class is of equal size - each class has the same number of values.
>
> *k-means*: The k-means clustering system creates classes of values such that the sum of the squared distance from each value to the center of its respective class is minimized.
>
> *continuous*: Equivalent to choosing equal intervals and increasing the number of classes to infinity. Would just return [min, max]

Chroma.js is able to [return colors as array](https://github.com/gka/chroma.js/issues/14) to interface it with [geostats](https://github.com/simogeo/geostats).

Answer (score 1):

The classInt (class intervals) "R" package documentation from R. Bivand describes several standard algorithms used to determine the ranges :

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/classInt/index.html